# Minitest-Capybara test assertion fails when run as "rake minitest:all" and "rake minitest:features" but fine otherwise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, integration-testing, minitest

When I run the test as either of the following, it **passes**:

```
bundle exec ruby -I test test/features/foo_test.rb

bundle exec ruby -I test test/features/foo_test.rb -n test_bar
```

Whereas when I run as either of the following, it **fails**:

```
bundle exec rake minitest:features RAILS_ENV=test

bundle exec rake minitest:all RAILS_ENV=test
```

**Question:** What could be causing the difference?

Additional info: When run as `minitest:features` or `minitest:all`, `div.field_with_errors` is missing.

I have tried the following combos:

- `minitest-rails (0.9.2)`
- `minitest-rails-capybara (0.10.0)`

and

- `minitest-rails (1.0.1)`
- `minitest-rails-capybara (1.0.0)`

The app is running on rails `4.0.5`.

Comment: Try running without `RAILS_ENV=test`.